# How to send data hex or base64 with websocketsharp in C#

Tags: c#, websocket-sharp

How do I connect to WS with  library and send data while it is encrypted with base64 or hex?
This is data form chromedev-tool

image 1: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rc07.png)

image 2 :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNw0F.png)

And this is my code (I tried with 3 different cases ):

```
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(address);

 string database64 = "8wYBAAEBaf/7iac=";
 string datastring = "......i....";
 string datahex = "f306 0100 0101 69ff fb89 a7";
 ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
 {
 ws.Send(database64);
 ws.Send(datastring);
 ws.Send(datahex);

 };
```

How could i resolve the problem ,please ?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i want send data same chromedev-tool , but i can't send then they are binary or hex or base64